# AfxBeginThread corrupts a LPWSTR value inside a class that is passed to the thread function as argument. Why?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

Look at this code:

```
// Function that start the thread
...
data = (PWTools::Data*)malloc(sizeof(PWTools::Data));
data->aParam1 = aParam1;
data->dataSourceName = pwTools.GetActiveDataSourceName(); //This function returns a LPWSTR
CWinThread* thread = AfxBeginThread(DeleteDocument, (LPVOID)data, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED);
...
```

After the line 3 above, data is filled properly with no problems. But immediatally after line 4, just after call AfxBeginThread, data->dataSourceName is corrupted and gets a non sense value. I tried to get the code inside GetActiveDataSourceName method and put it in the code above and everything works ok. But I don't want to resolve it this way. Why it happens? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are two forms of AfxBeginThread() and you are calling the five parameter version I think : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e.aspx

Comment: Show us the DeleteDocument function. What happens if you modify the DeleteDocument so it just returns without doing anything ? I bet data->dataSourceName won't be corrupted anymore. Probably the DeleteDocument function messes around with data.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the five parameter function. Is there any problem with that, Oakdale?

Comment: data->dataSourceName gets corrupted before entering the DeleteDocument thread function. I know it because I created the thread suspended and it only starts when I resume it. So, I call AfxBeginThread, the data->dataSourceName is corrupted and just after I call resume in thread. Anyway, here is the DeleteDocument function:

    ...
    PWTools::Data *filledData;
    filledData = (PWTools::Data*)malloc(sizeof(PWTools::Data));
    filledData = (PWTools::Data*)data;
    ...
In the code above, data->aParam1 is ok, but data->dataSourceName is corrupted.

Comment: CWinThread* AfxBeginThread( 
   CRuntimeClass* pThreadClass, 
   int nPriority = THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 
   UINT nStackSize = 0, 
   DWORD dwCreateFlags = 0, 
   LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttrs = NULL  
); So where is the pParam??

Answer (score 4):

Functions that return a pointer to a C string are always highly suspect.  They are hard to use, are you supposed to call free() to release the string?  Or delete[]?  Or SysFreeString?  Or LocalFree()?  Or not release it all?  My crystal ball has a pretty good guess at what that function looks like:

```
LPWSTR GetActiveDataSourceName()
{
    WCHAR retval[666];
    // Do stuff to fill retval
    //...
    return retval;
}
```

Which works, for a while, until you call a function that re-uses the stack space where "retval" is stored.  Instantly corrupting the string.   Any non-trivial function, AfxBeginThread() certainly qualifies.

You've tagged this question with [c++], return an std::wstring instead.